# How do I get the hash of current .exe?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, md5

**[SOLVED]**: I copied the file and ran the hasher on that copy.

I need my app to find the EXE's current MD5. I can get the MD5 of any file.
However, no matter what I do, I cannot get a FileStream to read the open EXE. I tried using FileOptions.Asynchronous but that didn't help.

EDIT: I guess I'm not very clear. I want my app to be be able to read itself.

EDIT to code:

```
private void GetMd5()
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
    FileStream stream = File.Create(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, (int)fi.Length, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

    md5.ComputeHash(stream);

    stream.Close();

    string rtrn = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < md5.Hash.Length; i++)
    {
        rtrn += (md5.Hash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    MessageBox.Show(rtrn.ToUpper());
}
```

Comment: Opening your own executing EXE seems like something that can't work, but I've never even considered it before, so I can't say for sure. Have you considered making a temporary copy of the EXE and running the hash on that, instead?

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I used File.Copy to %temp% and ran it on that.

Comment: It really shouldn't be necessary to copy the file.  It should just be a matter of opening it with the right access mode.  (If it can be copied, it can be read.)

Comment: @AndrewMock you should accept an answer or write your own answer and accept it, to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4):

The [File.Create Method (String, Int32, FileOptions, FileSecurity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143361.aspx):

> Creates or overwrites the specified file with the specified buffer
>   size, file options, and file security.

I'm fairly sure that's not what you intended to do. Presumably you want [FileInfo.Open Method (FileMode, FileAccess)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzdw7xcy.aspx):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path); 
FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but was recently trying to do this myself. In .NET 4.5 the following works quite nicely without the need for making a temporary copy. As said, if you can read the file to make a copy of it, you can read the file to generate a hash for it.

```
private string GetMD5()
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    md5.ComputeHash(stream);

    stream.Close();

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < md5.Hash.Length; i++)
        sb.Append(md5.Hash[i].ToString("x2"));

    return sb.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `FileStream stream = File.Create(path, (int)fi.Length, FileOptions.Asynchronous);` to `FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);`

Comment: If the file in question has already been locked by another process, then you can't open it. That's the way it works! Have you determine which process has the file open?

Comment: The app itself. I'm trying to get the app to open itself. I take it that it will not work.

Comment: @AndrewMock: You need to specify a read operation (i.e., File.OpenRead).  You should have no problem reading if it is locked, you just can't change it.  Either way... this is very strange.  There is probably a better way to solve your problem, whatever that problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've tried these answers and found that none of them change every edit to the exe, or change at all, I found something that actually does work.

I did not edit any code here, all of this was from the referred page below.

Reference: http://www.vcskicks.com/self-hashing.php

```
internal static class ExecutingHash
{
    public static string GetExecutingFileHash()
    {
        return MD5(GetSelfBytes());
    }

    private static string MD5(byte[] input)
    {
        return MD5(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(input));
    }

    private static string MD5(string input)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes).Replace("-", "");
    }

    private static byte[] GetSelfBytes()
    {
        string path = Application.ExecutablePath;

        FileStream running = File.OpenRead(path);

        byte[] exeBytes = new byte[running.Length];
        running.Read(exeBytes, 0, exeBytes.Length);

        running.Close();

        return exeBytes;
    }
}
```

Every test seems to output properly. I'd recommend to anyone seeing this to use this class or make something of it.