# Securly Storing Data in a C# application on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, windows-10, tpm

I have a C# application - for these purposes it only runs on Windows 10 - that needs to securely store data (keys, passwords, really anything) It needs to do so in a way that is inaccessible to any reader/writer other than the application itself.

The application is signed so the OS should be able to securely identify if the requester is the application (or an upgraded version of itself.)

My inclination is that this is exactly what TPM should facilitate but I've been unable to find anything that appears to address this situation. Maybe I'm just overthinking this but everything I've thought about allows the data to be read by a user context - meaning that if the right user account on that machine is compromised the data would be readable (which is what I want to prevent.)

Comment: @KenWhite - That is just it's common use case. It can be used for more than just drive encryption. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/trusted-platform-module-overview

Comment: @KenWhite - I never said I wanted or needed direct TPM access. I just said it could be used for more than Bitlocker (the fact that you said Crypto API uses TPM just proves it has applications beyond Bitlocker.)

Comment: TPM is a passive device. It would be nice if it could check your application's signature before processing a request, but it can't. Your application could be measured into the TPM, but Windows is not there yet AFAIK. I think the best you can do is create a TPM key or store something in NV RAM and then protect it with a password that only your application knows about.

Comment: I think you're trying to break catch 22. Which seems to be imposible. For whatever acess/encrypted data you need a key. A key can be user's password, certificate, HW token. If you put one of these in your app, they can be reverse-engineered (except HW token, if it's removable). Trying to store key in a cloud, and cloud access key in the app doesn't change the situation, just adds a layer. Therefore, user password or removable HW token is the only option really. Also, thik of: if users' account compromised -- it's their responsibility, but if your app is compromised -- then it's yours.

Comment: @Max - This is the situation I'm trying to overcome hoping their is some capability via the OS (Win 10) to secure data to an application. I can accept that if the kernel is hacked that all goes out the window - but those hacks are few and far between (so the risk is reasonable.) What I'm describing is completely doable by the OS - I'm just trying to figure out if Windows implements such capability and, if so, how to utilize it from C#/.NET.

Comment: @Nicknow. I have a craizy idea to think of (it may be a complete rubbish at the end of day), but what if caclulate application executable hash and use it as a key for standard OS encryption? It's imposible if anyone can create another executalbe with the same hash to read your secrets. But this turn updates and debugging into a nightmare. You need to find a mechanism for an old version to decrypt old data, pass it to the new version and save.

Comment: @Max - How do I get the app's executable hash in C#?

Comment: @Nicknow, have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875296/how-do-i-get-the-hash-of-current-exe. I also thought about data transfer between versions: you will need to ask user for help -- make a one-off backup password and enter it twice (3 times) for backup (2 times) and for restore to the new version (1 time).